# How do I solve this recurrence equation?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, recurrence-relation

I have to express the solution of the recurrence equation T(n) = T(an) + n where a is a constant,  0 < a < 1, in terms of θ using the iteration method. I am unsure of how I calculate the cost of each level and the number of levels because of the constant a.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve $$T(n)=T(\tilde{a}n)+n$$

you can apply the Master
Theorem(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)):

the recurrence:
\begin{equation}
    T(n)
      = \begin{cases}
          a T(n / b) + f(n) & n > 1 \\
          T_1           & n = 1
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
with constants $a \geq 1$, (b > 1),
the function  (f(n) > 0),
with constants $ \alpha = \log_b a $
has the solution::
\begin{equation*}
      T(n)
        = \begin{cases}
            \Theta(n^{\alpha})
               & \text{\(f(n) = O(n^c)\) para \(c < \alpha\)} \\
            \Theta(n^{\alpha})
               & \text{\(f(n) = \Theta(n^{\alpha} \log^\beta n)\)
                       con \(\beta < -1\)} \\
            \Theta(n^{\alpha} \log \log n)
               & \text{\(f(n) = \Theta(n^{\alpha} \log^\beta n)\)
                       con \(\beta = -1\)} \\
            \Theta(n^{\alpha} \log^{\beta + 1} n)
               & \text{\(f(n) = \Theta(n^{\alpha} \log^\beta n)\)
                       with \(\beta > -1\)} \\
            \Theta(f(n))
              & \text{\(f(n) = \Omega(n^c)\) with \(c > \alpha\)
                      y \(a f(n / b) < k f(n)\)}\\
            &\text{for \(n\) large
                      with \(k < 1\)}
          \end{cases}
    \end{equation*}
in our case:
$a=1$, $b=\frac{1}{\tilde{a}}$ and $f(n)=n$  $\Rightarrow \alpha=0$

so
\begin{aligned}
T(n)&=\Theta(f(n))\\
&=\Theta(n)\\
\end{aligned}
otherwise, as it says Yves Daoust:

\begin{aligned}
T(n)&=T(\tilde{a}n)+n\\
&=(T(\tilde{a}^2n)+\tilde{a}n)+n\\
&=((T(\tilde{a}^3n)+\tilde{a}^2n)+\tilde{a}n+n)\\
&\vdots\\
&\text{notice that we have a polynomial of n}\\
&=T(\tilde{a}^m n)+ \Theta(n)\\
\end{aligned}
where, for finite m (when does the recursion stop?)
$$T(n)=\Theta(n)$$
I suppose that for that m $T(\tilde{a}^m\cdot n)$ it has a constant cost (the base case, as Yves says).

The base case is important when defining recurrence!

to do it exactly you must calculate the sum of the m terms:

\begin{aligned}
T(n)&=((T(\tilde{a}^3n)+\tilde{a}^2n)+\tilde{a}n+n)\\
&=T(\tilde{a}^m n)+ n\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(\tilde{a}^i)\\
&=T(\tilde{a}^m n)+n\frac{1-\tilde{a}^m}{1-\tilde{a}}\\
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$T(n)=T(an)+n=T(a^2n)+an+n=T(a^3n)+a^2n+an+n=\cdots$$

You can stop the expansion when $a^kn=1$ and use the geometric sum formula.

Comment: Another hint : You should verify your solution by using substitution

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Making $n = a^m$ we have

$$
T(a^m) = T(a^{m+1})+a^m
$$

or recasting

$$
R(m+1) = R(m) - a^m
$$

etc.